# Should the hot water heater be replaced?

Tags: discussion

I don't mind an unnamed user editing *hot* out of *hot water heater* but their choice of replacing *hot* with *cold* results in the rather uncommon construction of *cold water heater* which far worse than even *water heater* which should be preferred. They might find *hot water heater* to be an oxymoron but it is rather common and doesn't sound as unnatural as *cold water heater* does.

Examples:

[Gas Cold Water Heater Discharges in Winter](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/61103/why-would-a-gas-water-heater-discharge-water-in-the-winter)

[Why is my brand new PEX clear tubing turning green near the cold water heater?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7844/why-is-my-brand-new-pex-clear-tubing-turning-green-near-the-water-heater)

[When do tankless cold water heaters need to be descaled?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/54131/when-do-tankless-cold-water-heaters-need-to-be-descaled)

[Cold water heater installed wrong?!?! why do all 3](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/60779/cold-water-heater-installed-wrong-why-do-all-3)

[Should I run 1/2“ pex from a manifold to each fixture or 3/4”?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/59551/should-i-run-1-2-pex-from-a-manifold-to-each-fixture-or-3-4)

[What to do when the cold water valve on the cold water heater is welded on?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58916/what-to-do-when-the-cold-water-valve-on-the-cold-water-heater-is-welded-on)

[Why is cold water coming out of my HW OUT-TAKE pipe?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/57992/why-is-cold-water-coming-out-of-my-hw-out-take-pipe)

[Fast hot water - tankless heater as backup or recirculator](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/55866/fast-hot-water-tankless-heater-as-backup-or-recirculator)

[Electric water boiler .. how is the system supposed to work? (UK)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/54014/electric-water-boiler-how-is-the-system-supposed-to-work-uk)

[Bench soldering copper pipe into a subassembly](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/53870/bench-soldering-copper-pipe-into-a-subassembly)

[Low hot water pressure in one fixture after water heater replacement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52645/low-hot-water-pressure-in-one-fixture-after-water-heater-replacement)

[Do I need to shut off the gas to my water heater, when I shut off the cold water intake to fix a leaking hot water faucet in my basement sink?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52435/do-i-need-to-shut-off-the-gas-to-my-water-heater-when-i-shut-off-the-cold-water)

[Is there any harm in turning my water heater to off or to pilot for perhaps six months?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52364/is-there-any-harm-in-turning-my-water-heater-to-off-or-to-pilot-for-perhaps-six)

[Why is the gas water heater pressure valve leaking after installing recirculation pump & old radiator?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51405/why-is-the-gas-water-heater-pressure-valve-leaking-after-installing-recirculatio)

[How can I stop the humming produced by my water heater blower motor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51273/how-can-i-stop-the-humming-produced-by-my-water-heater-blower-motor)

[What's causing the smell in my basement?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49788/whats-causing-the-smell-in-my-basement)

[What could cause my electric water heater to over heat water?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48727/what-could-cause-my-electric-water-heater-to-over-heat-water)

[Hot Water Through Cold Water Side](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48187/hot-water-through-cold-water-side)

...

***NOTE:*** The linked questions have been edited to use "water heater", so you'll have to view the revision history to see the "cold water heater" edits.

Comment: That sounds like an edit that should have been rejected. Which post was this on?

Comment: Most recently http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/61103; look at the revisions. But there were others in the past by the same user.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Would you like to comment on this discussion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"*Water heater*" is probably the best term to use.

See [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hot+water+heater%2Ccold+water+heater%2Cwater+heater&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Chot%20water%20heater%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhot%20water%20heater%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHot%20Water%20Heater%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHot%20water%20heater%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHOT%20WATER%20HEATER%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwater%20heater%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwater%20heater%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWater%20Heater%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWATER%20HEATER%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWater%20heater%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwater%20Heater%3B%2Cc0)

[image]